# onmouseover on window.createpopup

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

We have a code with menu with sub menus where submenu is created through window.createpopup
We have onmouseover event to display submenu or popup and then we will select the submenu

This is working fine in windows ie 11 but in windows 10, when we take the mouse to the submenu that is the popup window it automatically hides

Please help me in this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You'll need to provide some code if you want some help. You can see how to write a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TheBlacksmith i cant share the code as per the restrictions by the company ☹️

Comment: Without us being able to see the code you'll struggle to receive an answer. It's very difficult to debug code that you cannot see.